# Is there a way to programmatically create App ids?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, ios-provisioning, app-id

I'd like to programmatically create App ids in the iOS provisioning portal. I can't use wildcards because I need the push notification system.

Is there way to do it in commandline ?

Comment: Why do you need to do this? There might be a workaround.

Comment: Because I need to auto-generate applications, including publishing.

Comment: That's not possible. You must go through the iOS Provisioning Portal and create each App ID manually.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible. You can use [fastlane/produce](https://github.com/fastlane/produce).
It's open source.

https://github.com/fastlane/produce